# Change woocommerce product status from private to publish using direct link

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to generate a link or may be a simple product link with some args to change the status of the product. So when I give that link to anyone he opens the link and then the status of the product change from private to publish and remain publish all the time until I change back from the admin side.

I have tried using this code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'cs_change_product_status', 10 );

function cs_change_product_status(){
        global $product;
        $status = $product->get_status();
        if($status == 'private'){
            $terms = get_the_terms ( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
            $cat_id = 0;
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $cat_id = $term->id;
                break;
            }
            if($cat_id === 75){
                wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $product->get_id(), 'post_status' => 'publish' ) );
            }
        }
    }
```

This is not working on the private products. I think wordpress not loading any woocommerce hook when the product is private and showing 404 error page.

Comment: Try use the template redirect hook.

Comment: Good idea, how I can get the product in that hook?

Comment: global $product ;

Comment: You can check is_product()

Comment: Where should the link be displayed? Who has access to change the status? You don't appear to be checking authorization at all. And why should a user have the authority change a post's status?

Comment: @helgatheviking it is for a one category. And yes no authorization at all. Can yo help in that sense?

Comment: @Dmitry your given solution is not working for the logged-out users.